# Creating a function to convert data across many documents and collections in Firebase Firestore

Tags: firebase, google-cloud-firestore, google-cloud-functions

I am new to Firebase Functions and have been scouring the internet to try and find resources that would be most useful to me.

The problem I am trying to solve is: when a user currently updates their units of measurements, for either height or weight, the data in Firestore does not update to match the new unit. Therefore, the numbers and the units look rather jarring. The project is based around health and fitness, so the units of measurement focus on weight and height primarily.

What I am in need of is a cloud Function that will traverse through all documents finding specific Document values, taking the stored value and converting it to the new unit of measurement.

My first question is, at this time is this possible? Second, if it is possible in a Cloud Function, how could this look and work? And finally, if not, what could be done instead to minimize work client side?

I can provide more context if required, but appreciate any help or advice available!

Comment: Sure, you could do this.  My suggestion is to just start writing code to experiment with this and get to know how Cloud Functions works.  Also consider not doing this at all, and just convert the data to their preferred units at the time of display.

Comment: That is a really good idea to do it when accessed! I hadn't considered that. That could be a good first pass implementation. At a later stage the function will be needed to do mass conversions though, but thanks for the  suggestion!